# What is the point of the .trashes file in Mac Os X?

Tags: macos, file-management, trash, dir

What is the point of the '/.trashes' file in Mac Os X? It appears to be useless. I've never seen it being used by programmers. Would it be bad to delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the location of the trash bin.  If you use a USB drive on your Mac and then you plug it into a Windows or Linux PC, you'll see that same file/folder.
Every drive will have its own.

Comment: Would it be bad to delete it?

Comment: @John: Go ahead and delete it -- OS X will recreate it next time it's needed.